# read and display text file in the console with time delay?

Tags: java

I am trying to print the content of my text file into the console but with time delay, for example 2 seconds for each line.

This is my text file content:

```
David
1
1
Chris
1
2
David
2
1
Chris
1
3
David
3
1
```

and this is my code so far:

```
File f = new File("actions.txt");
try{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0); // terminate the program
}
```

any help would be great(im a beginner)

Comment: `Timer.sleep(delay time in milliseconds);`

Comment: thanks for quick reply , at the moment it doesn't display the content of the text file, was wondering if there is more efficient way to display the contents. (I am a beginner).

Comment: @Juvanis - You'd have made that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
File f = new File("actions.txt");
try{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0); // terminate the program
```

}